# How to output data to html after reading from csv file?

Tags: html, regex, csv, tcl

I have a **CSV** file. I tried reading it and splitting it on comma basis and put it in `HTML table`, does not work.
**CSV** file looks like this- 
    Name, number, address
    abc, 1, z
    pqr, 0, w

The table headers would be name, address, number
TD would be the remaining data

```
set FileName "file.csv"
catch {set fptr [open $FileName r]}  
set contents [read -nonewline $fptr] 
set splitCont [split $contents ","]

foreach line $splitCont {
    if { [regexp -nocase {^\s*Name} $line val] } {
    puts $filep "<TR><TH valign=top>$val</TH>\n"
    }
puts $filep "</TR>"
} 
close $fptr
puts $filep "</TABLE>"
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? What kind of output are you getting and what would you want to get? Right now you would at least be missing the proper `td`/`th` tags. In addition a table should not contain an `h2` (turn those lines around).

Answer (score 0):

```
set htmlFile "aborted_jobs.html"
set filep [open $htmlFile w]

puts $filep "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Aborted Jobs Summary</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>"
puts $filep "<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=4 align=center>\n"
puts $filep "<H2 align=center>Aborted Jobs Summary</H2>"

set FileName "aborted_jobs.csv"
catch {set fptr [open $FileName r]}  
set contents [read -nonewline $fptr] 
set splitCont [split $contents "\n"]

foreach line $splitCont {
    set cellList [split $line ","]
    set tableHeader 0 
    if { [regexp -nocase {InstanceName} $cellList] } {
        set tableHeader 1
    }
    puts $filep "<TR>"
    foreach data $cellList {
            if {$tableHeader} {
                puts $filep "<TH valign=top>$data</TH>"
            } else {
                puts $filep "<TD>$data</TD>"
            }
    }
    puts $filep "</TR>"
} 
close $fptr
puts $filep "</TABLE>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little long, but it's much easier to extend and to avoid errors than if you read the csv or write the html by hand.

```
package require tdom
package require csv
package require struct::queue

set doc [dom createDocument html]
set root [$doc documentElement]
$root appendXML "<HEAD><TITLE>Aborted Jobs Summary</TITLE></HEAD>"
set body [$doc createElement body]
$root appendChild $body
set h2 [$doc createElement h2]
$h2 appendChild [$doc createTextNode "Aborted Jobs Summary"]
$h2 setAttribute align center
$body appendChild $h2
set table [$doc createElement table]
$table setAttribute border 1 cellpadding 4 align center
$body appendChild $table

set FileName "aborted_jobs.csv"
if {[catch {open $FileName} f]} {
    # just rethrow unless you want to handle it
    return -code error $f
}

::struct::queue q
::csv::read2queue $f q
close $f

set tr [$doc createElement tr]
$table appendChild $tr

foreach header [q get] {
    set th [$doc createElement th]
    $th appendChild [$doc createTextNode $header]
    $th setAttribute valign top
    $tr appendChild $th
}

while {[q size] > 0} {
    set tr [$doc createElement tr]
    $table appendChild $tr

    foreach data [q get] {
        set td [$doc createElement td]
        $td appendChild [$doc createTextNode $data]
        $tr appendChild $td
    }
}

set htmlFile "aborted_jobs.html"
set filep [open $htmlFile w]
$doc asXML -channel $filep
close $filep
```

The `tdom` document object has an `asHTML` method as well, I usually use `asXML` instead even for html documents.

Documentation:
[catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[csv (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[struct::queue (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/queue.html),
[tdom (package)](http://tdom.github.io),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)